# Convert TXT/CSV to JSON in Python 3

Tags: pandas, csv, encoding, automation, missing-data

I need help converting all rows from a simple .txt file to JSON.  I am trying to convert the .txt to .csv, and then .csv to JSON using the pandas library.  However, I am unable to capture all rows from the original .txt file in the output JSON.

Here is the file (data.txt), listed row by row:

```
Images
Median of 100 points per image
Dataset
76 out of 77 images calibrated (98%), all images enabled
Camera Optimization
0.60% difference in initial and optimized camera parameters
Matches
Median of 1000 matches per image
Georeferencing
Yes, 3D GCP
```

Here is the code I am attempting to use to convert .txt to .csv:

```
import csv

with open('C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\image_metadata.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
    with open('C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\image_metadata.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

I must note that rows where text is separated by a comma ( , ) are listed in two separate cells within the .csv, but when I try to write the CSV to JSON those specific rows are omitted from the JSON file.  Here is the code I use to attempt conversion from .csv to JSON.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\image_metadata.csv", header=None, error_bad_lines=False, encoding='utf-8')
df.to_json("C:\\Users\\mdl518\\Desktop\\image_metadata.json", orient="table")
```

For the output JSON, I am not overly concerned about the index names (even n0, n1, etc.. tags are acceptable) - I just need to be able to capture the rows of the .txt/.csv with commas separating the text in the output JSON, any assistance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script tailored to your input file structure, stores the content in a dictionary, and writes the dictionary to a JSON file:

```
with open('untitled.txt') as file_handle:
    file_content = file_handle.read()

my_dict = {}
for line in file_content.split('\n'):
    if line.startswith('Median') and ("points per image" in line):
        print('median points per image:',line.split(' ')[2])
        my_dict['median points per image:'] = line.split(' ')[2]
    elif "images calibrated" in line:
        print('lower:',line.split(' ')[0]) 
        my_dict['lower:'] = line.split(' ')[0]
        print('total:',line.split(' ')[3])
        my_dict['total:'] = line.split(' ')[3]
        print('percentage:',line.split(' ')[6].replace('(','').replace('%)',''))
        my_dict['percentage:'] = line.split(' ')[6].replace('(','').replace('%)','')
    elif "difference in" in line:
        print('difference:',line.split(' ')[0])
        my_dict['difference:'] = line.split(' ')[0]
    elif line.startswith("Median") and "matches per image" in line:
        print('median matches per image:',line.split(' ')[2])
        my_dict['median matches per image:'] = line.split(' ')[2]
        
import json
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:  
    json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

I left the print statements in so that you can see what is being loaded into the dictionary as it is created.